# angular verifing data with database on click

Tags: angular

to put it simply my button does update the state of the object like change it's step (exemple : i have 3 situation step 1 / step 2 /step 3 if the object is in step 1 it's accessable from my space and i click the button to change the step to step2 orr step 3 depands on what i chose, if it's not on step 1 the admin access that ) anyway my problem is that there are multiple user who can change the step from step 1 to step 2 or step 3  so when i select the file which is on step 1 i have to check the step with the database if it's still on step 1 when i click on change step , what i'm getting is that when i call the fonction to do comparison on angular it does change the step then get me the data to compare with , i did try to block the change step to wait for the data but what i get is that i have to double click on the button which is not helpful so is there anyway to verifie that the data / objet i have is the same on the database instantly when i click on the button cause the typescript does get the data after affecting the rest of the button fonction
thank you for reading this feel free to suggest solutions

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet, or a stackblitz with a demo?

Comment: nvm that i found a round way for this and it was to use (mouseover)='syncfiche(element)' as the first trigger for the element and then on (click)='docompareandthefunction()'

Answer (score 0):

the solution i used was to trigger the button with mouseover and get the element from the database then when click do the comparison and the rest hope it helps someone